# Value Converter Without Binding On Image Source

Tags: wpf, image, binding, converters

I need to get the path of an image through a value converter. However I can't find any examples of using a value converter without binding.

I would be looking to do something along these lines:

```
<Image source="{Value=Image1, Converter={ImageConverter}}" />
```

The image converter will then go check an image folder and return the correct file path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use a `Binding` like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, ConverterParameter=Image1}"/>
```

Won't that suffice?